# How to put props.children in JSX tag

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components

I have a component like this one:

```
class Person extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { language } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        I speak {language}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And a Higher order component like this:

```
export default (BaseComponent) => 
  class extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return <BaseComponent language="English" />;
    }
  }
```

I used them:

```
class PersonList extends Component {
  render() {
    const NewPerson = hoc(Person)
    return <NewPerson />;
  }
}
```

Which was perfectly fine, it output what I wanted

```
I speak English
```

But what if I want the PersonList component to render something passed down from its parent instead of imported, like this:

```
render(
  <PersonList>
    <Person />
  </PersonList>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

Now,

```
const NewPerson = hoc(Person)
```

throws an error.

I known that I can fix the HOC like this

```
return <div>{React.cloneElement(BaseComponent, { language: "English" })}</div>
```

But this is a breaking change, I don't want to do this.

Are there anyway I can archive my goal (HOC component renders something that passed down instead of imported) without breaking my HOC ?

Or there are any work around ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a Person component created by a Higher order component this way:

```
const NewPerson = hoc(Person)
render(
  <PersonList>
    <NewPerson />
  </PersonList>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

Add `{this.props.children}` to your PersonList's render function:

```
class PersonList extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
          {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: So simple and it points me to the right direction. But you answer has a little syntax error. It should be <this.props.children /> instead of {this.props.children}. Please edit so that I can mark this one ask the answer.

Comment: No, `{this.props.children}` is correct: https://learn.co/lessons/react-this-props-children

Comment: Have you tried it ? In my project, {this.props.children} showed nothing, but <this.props.children /> good.
This also works: const NewPerson = hoc(Person) then put <NewPerson /> inside <PersonList>

Comment: Apparently, {hoc(Person)} is like {Person} instead of <Person /> so we need <this.props.children /> .

Comment: You were right with the NewPerson component. I approved your edit suggestion.

Comment: You probably will add somethings into PersonList's render function rather than just simply show the children. I added `<div>`s as the simplest.